# Display search button (image) next to search box

Tags: html, css

trying to get the search button (image) to display either next to or inside the search box. Everything I try, the search button(image) always ends up below the search box and centered for some reason.

```
<form id="navigationSearchForm" action="http://products.divalsafety.com/storefrontCommerce/search.do" method="get" name="searchForm" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <input id="searchInputBox" type="text" name="keyword" size="25" maxlength="75" value="">
            <span id="keywordspan" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"><label>keyword</label>
                <input id="keywordInput" type="text" name="searchType" value="keyword" size="12" maxlength="10">
            </span> 
            <span id="emailspan" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"><label>E-mail</label>
                <input id="emailAddressInput" type="text" name="emailAddress" size="12" maxlength="20">
            </span>
        <input id="searchGoButton" style="width: 27px;" type="image" src="/images/searchbutton27px.png" alt="Search">
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pf6qQ - for some reason it shows up to the right on fiddle but on my Joomla site it's always centered and below the search box. Ultimately I'm looking to get it in the search box

Comment: there might be some other css that is affecting your element. try to check parent of `<form>` may be it has fix width that causing span to go below.

Comment: great thought! There was some other CSS affecting it. I removed that code and we are good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define your css separately and not inline in your HTML.  Despite this, I've taken your code and added a position style to the search image.  This should work.

Try this:

```
    <form id="navigationSearchForm" action="http://products.divalsafety.com/storefrontCommerce/search.do" method="get" name="searchForm" accept-charset="UTF-8">

        <input id="searchInputBox" type="text" name="keyword" size="25" maxlength="75" value=""></input>

         <span id="keywordspan" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"><label>keyword</label>

         <input id="keywordInput" type="text" name="searchType" value="keyword" size="12" maxlength="10"></input>
         </span> 

        <span id="emailspan" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"><label>E-mail</label>
        <input id="emailAddressInput" type="text" name="emailAddress" size="12" maxlength="20"></input>
        </span>

        <input id="searchGoButton" style="width: 27px; position:relative; left:-40px; top:10px;" type="image" src="/images/searchbutton27px.png" alt="Search"></input>
    </form>
```

Comment: This also worked for me once the CSS code was removed that was affecting certain identifiers in this code. Thanks for the reply and help!